# Error trying install popper.js with npm

Tags: angular, npm

**Hi, I have a problem trying to install popper.js through npm. I get the following error:**

```
npm ERR! path 
/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/p/comicapp/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo npm 
ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! syscall rename npm ERR! enoent 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 
'/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/p/comicapp/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo' ->'/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/p/comicapp/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.dezalgo.DELETE' npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm 
ERR! enoent
```

Comment: try to run `npm install` again

Comment: i have tried many times with npm install popper.js --save, it worked for jquery to install jquery.

Comment: Looks like you may need to reinstall npm, or maybe try uninstalling jquery https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13492

Comment: This problem was solved for me in two ways:
1.- Install version 4 of npm
    
                          or

2.- Installing first jquery and then popper

I needed this to use bootstrap 4.